# Edges cant be beveled

Tags: bevel

Could someone maybe figure out why the edges in this model can not be beveled?

All the other edges can be beveled but the one selected not.

In the file the edges that I would like to bevel are alread selected and mesh is in edit mode

[image]

Comment: There is a inner surface on top of the cylinder part: delete it.

Comment: Thanks that did it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Because these edges have three adjacent faces. I gues you dont need the n-gon one, so  if you delete it you can bevel the edge.

Please see the screencast for demonstration.[image]